# Recursive regex: Unrecognized grouping construct

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have written a regex to parse a BibTex entry, but I think I used something that is not allowed in .net as I am getting a `Unrecognized grouping construct` 
exception.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
(?<entry>@(\w+)\{(\w+),(?<kvp>\W*([a-zA-Z]+) = \{(.+)\},)(?&kvp)*(\W*([a-zA-Z]+) = \{(.+)\})\W*\},?\s*)(?&entry)*
```

Can be seen at https://regex101.com/r/uM0mV1/1

Comment: Oh, recursing named subpatterns with `(?&...)` is not supported.

Comment: Is there something equivalent I can use?

Comment: Just declare a variable and then build the regex using `string.Format`.

Comment: I can't see how that would fix my problem..

Comment: You are trying to shorten the regex pattern by re-using pattern parts with recursing the named subpatterns. Right? You can't do that in .NET. Build the regex "dynamically". I will try to illustrate it now. This is [what I mean](http://ideone.com/VwAAfT). However, I think there is some issue with your regex. Do you want to match all the individual entries?

Comment: I'd do it like this in .NET: [`@(?<type>\w+)\{(?<name>\w+),(?<kvps>\s*(?<attribute>\w+)\s*=\s*\{(?<value>.*?)},?\r?\n)+}`](http://goo.gl/rGmert). To access all key-value pairs, I'd use the `.Groups["kvps"].Captures` property and/or `.Groups["attribute"].Captures` and `.Groups["value"].Captures`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would capture all the details in the string you provided:

```
@(?<type>\w+)\{(?<name>\w+),(?<kvps>\s*(?<attribute>\w+)\s*=\s*\{(?<value>.*?)},?\r?\n)+}
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40(%3F%3Ctype%3E%5Cw%2B)%5C%7B(%3F%3Cname%3E%5Cw%2B)%2C(%3F%3Ckvps%3E%5Cs*(%3F%3Cattribute%3E%5Cw%2B)%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%5C%7B(%3F%3Cvalue%3E.*%3F)%7D%2C%3F%5Cr%3F%5Cn)%2B%7D&i=%40article%7BGettys90%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20author%20%3D%20%7BJim%20Gettys%20and%20Phil%20Karlton%20and%20Scott%20McGregor%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20abstract%20%3D%20%7BA%20technical%20overview%20of%20the%20X11%20functionality.%20This%20is%20an%20update%20of%20the%20X10%20TOG%20paper%20by%20Scheifler%20%5C%26%20Gettys.%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20journal%20%3D%20%7BSoftware%20Practice%20and%20Experience%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20volume%20%3D%20%7B20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20number%20%3D%20%7BS2%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20title%20%3D%20%7BThe%20%7BX%7D%20Window%20System%2C%20Version%2011%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20year%20%3D%20%7B1990%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%40article%7BGettys90%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20author%20%3D%20%7BJim%20Gettys%20and%20Phil%20Karlton%20and%20Scott%20McGregor%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20abstract%20%3D%20%7BA%20technical%20overview%20of%20the%20X11%20functionality.%20This%20is%20an%20update%20of%20the%20X10%20TOG%20paper%20by%20Scheifler%20%5C%26%20Gettys.%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20journal%20%3D%20%7BSoftware%20Practice%20and%20Experience%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20volume%20%3D%20%7B20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20number%20%3D%20%7BS2%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20title%20%3D%20%7BThe%20%7BX%7D%20Window%20System%2C%20Version%2011%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20year%20%3D%20%7B1990%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%40article%7BGettys90%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20author%20%3D%20%7BJim%20Gettys%20and%20Phil%20Karlton%20and%20Scott%20McGregor%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20abstract%20%3D%20%7BA%20technical%20overview%20of%20the%20X11%20functionality.%20This%20is%20an%20update%20of%20the%20X10%20TOG%20paper%20by%20Scheifler%20%5C%26%20Gettys.%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20journal%20%3D%20%7BSoftware%20Practice%20and%20Experience%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20volume%20%3D%20%7B20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20number%20%3D%20%7BS2%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20title%20%3D%20%7BThe%20%7BX%7D%20Window%20System%2C%20Version%2011%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20year%20%3D%20%7B1990%7D%0D%0A%7D)

This regex works well because C# regex engine keeps all captured texts in a stack, and it can be accessed via [Groups["name"].Captures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

The C# code showing how to use it:

```
var pattern = @"@(?<type>\w+)\{(?<name>\w+),(?<kvps>\s*(?<attribute>\w+)\s*=\s*\{(?<value>.*?)},?\r?\n)+}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
var cnt = 1;
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nMatch {0}", cnt));
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["type"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < m.Groups["attribute"].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}",
              m.Groups["attribute"].Captures[i].Value,
              m.Groups["value"].Captures[i].Value));
     }
     cnt++;
}
```

Output:

```
Match 1
article
Gettys90
author - Jim Gettys and Phil Karlton and Scott McGregor
abstract - A technical overview of the X11 functionality. This is an update of the X10 TOG paper by Scheifler \& Gettys.
journal - Software Practice and Experience
volume - 20
number - S2
title - The {X} Window System, Version 11
year - 1990

Match 2
article
Gettys90
author - Jim Gettys and Phil Karlton and Scott McGregor
abstract - A technical overview of the X11 functionality. This is an update of the X10 TOG paper by Scheifler \& Gettys.
journal - Software Practice and Experience
volume - 20
number - S2
title - The {X} Window System, Version 11
year - 1990

Match 3
article
Gettys90
author - Jim Gettys and Phil Karlton and Scott McGregor
abstract - A technical overview of the X11 functionality. This is an update of the X10 TOG paper by Scheifler \& Gettys.
journal - Software Practice and Experience
volume - 20
number - S2
title - The {X} Window System, Version 11
year - 1990
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume your named backreference is wrong. [See MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az24scfc.aspx#backreference_constructs) Try following

```
(?<entry>@(\w+)\{(\w+),(?<kvp>\W*([a-zA-Z]+) = \{(.+)\},)\k<kvp>*(\W*([a-zA-Z]+) = \{(.+)\})\W*\},?\s*)\k<entry>*
```

Comment: The `\k` keyword matches only if the recursion is identical to the first (as far as I've understod) (https://regex101.com/r/aZ7xE3/1)

Comment: You are right. If repetition should not be identical, it's easier. You don't need backreference. Use quantifiers `+` instead: `(?<entry>@(\w+)\{(\w+),(?<kvp>\W*([a-zA-Z]+) = \{(.+)\},)+(\W*([a-zA-Z]+) = \{(.+)\})\W*\},?\s*)+`

Comment: That won't work either as it will generate only one match making it difficult to extract the data. (In my opinion). And the most of the data will be in an unmatched group. https://regex101.com/r/pU6jM6/1